# Wouldn't this vision present a logical paradox?

Tags: minority-report

At the end of the film it is revealed that...

> John Anderton was purposely placed in a position where he would likely kill Leo Crow and that Crow was told beforehand by Burgess that Anderton would come to his room (and was ordered to plant false evidence there to get Anderton angry enough to kill him). 
> But the only reason Anderton knew Crow's name and wanted to find him and successfully located him was because of information he got from the vision of the precogs. So it seems that part of the plan was that the precogs would see the murder and through their vision give Anderton the information he needed to kill Crow.

Why did

> Burgess

think that the precogs would envision a murder that would only take place as a result of their vision? Wouldn't it be a more logical assumption be that

> the murder would never take place since Anderton had no reason to pursue Crow?

Comment: If they didn't get a vision, that's nothing some anonymous tip can't solve.  We don't know exactly when Burgess started putting his plan together, but we know it's when Anderton started looking at Ann Lively that he knew he needed to.  Burgess would either have started to arrange the Crow scenario knowing eventually it would trigger the precogs, or arranged it after the vision to match the information in the vision (which he's done before).

Comment: You can use >! spoiler tags to hide important information rather than putting "This is a spoiler!!!" at the top of the question.

Comment: The answer is that his plan worked because of timey-wimey.

Comment: @Radhil The precogs didn't see the anonymous tip scenario, they saw the Anderton taking Agatha scenario. But he only took her because of the precogs vision. So the paradox remains.

Comment: @Jackman - then I'm not understanding.  *The Precogs Will See A Future Murder*.  Full Stop.  Burgess can't possibly plan that, he absolutely knows it will happen, he has to plan *around* it.  He would go as far as he needed to set up Leo Crow as Anderton's target up until the Precogs trigger, at which point Anderton's done anyway. There's no paradox here that doesn't exist with every other murder they see, except that Agatha becomes part of it, which no one could plan for.

Comment: @Jackman - do you think Burgess actually created the vision in the first place?  That would explain our disconnect - he can't, he never could have.

Comment: And if it's a paradox, so what? We're science fiction fans, awe read or watch time travel stories, we *like* paradoxes.

Answer (score 1):

The plan was to frame Anderton, this most likely would have been done by getting him into the room somehow and triggering a red ball (spur of the moment murder) from the precogs what happens instead is the precogs see a brown ball (premeditated murder).

In universe the precogs abilities are never really explained but it is shown they can see many possible futures.  Crows death was going to happen eventually as soon as Burgess decided he needed to get rid of Anderton, if the precogs could choose to show a vision early (or a vision of the future if x event occurs instead of y event) to manipulate events the movie becomes about Agatha manipulating events to achieve freedom.

Out of universe there would not have been much of a movie if the plan worked perfectly.